# Which cache should i use for in Memory in Azure environment

Tags: azure, caching

I wanted to use in memory  as a cache . I believe In -Role cache would serve as a In Memory cache .But as per MSDN

Azure Managed Cache Service and Azure In-Role Cache service will be retired on November 30, 2016

So other than redis cache we dont have any options?

Please let me know which I can use as In Memory Cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Redis Cache is the option right now.

Also you can use partner offerings from the Azure Marketplace, for example, [Tarantool from Mail.ru](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarantool) which is used by such companies like Badoo.
http://highscalability.com/blog/2015/12/30/how-to-choose-an-in-memory-nosql-solution-performance-measur.html.

Comment: can i use System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache in cloud web role project?